# Moodle html_table not allowing duplicate records

Tags: php, moodle

I am creating a HTML table using html_table() function in Moodle. Whenever I load the data into the table, it discards the duplicate records. What will be the problem here? Please provide the solution.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: It's not the HTML table that is removing duplicates, it will be the $DB code. Can you display the SQL you are using. The first column must be unique.

Comment: Yes, I got the solution. I was not using the first column id in SQL select query. Thanks for the answer.